# Sublime Text 3 не интерпретирует Haxe

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3, haxe

Если ставить автоматическую Build-system то при компиляции на Ctrl+B требует .flow файл хотя я использую .hxml файлы для настроек проекта. Вопрос, какую Build-system нужно использовать для сборки Haxe проектов в JS результат? И второй вопрос, как можно настроить Build-System чтобы можно было создавать проекты подобной структуры (показанной ниже) автоматический, т.е при компиляции формировать все папки (3 папки и файл настроек проекта .hxml)

Из установленных для HaXe пакетов стоит только Haxe

---

assets/

src/

bin/

projext.hxml

---

Comment: Чего вы хотите добиться, из текста вопроса я так и не понял. Попробуйте переформулировать. И заодно приложите список пакетов для Haxe, которые у вас в саблайме.

Comment: @D-side Если ставить автоматическую Build-system то при компиляции на Ctrl+B требует .flow файл хотя я использую .hxml файлы для настроек проекта. Вопрос, какую Build-system нужно использовать для сборки Haxe проектов в JS результат?

И второй вопрос, как можно настроить Build-System чтобы можно было создавать проекты подобной структуры как описал выше автоматический, т.е при компиляции формировать все папки (3 папки и файл настроек проекта .hxml)

Comment: Не стесняйтесь редактировать вопрос, чтобы он отражал суть детальнее. И список используемых пакетов для haxe не забудьте.

Comment: Решил данную проблему пересев на полноценную IDE FlashDevelop.